# How to stream text to a client using Flask without adding line breaks?

Tags: python, flask, stream

I need my Flask app to be able to stream text data that is generated on the fly.

To test Flask's streaming response, I'm using the following code:

Server-side route:

```py
@app.route('/test_streaming')
def test_streaming():
    def generate():
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            yield str(i)
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text')
```

Client-side test request:

```py
url = "http://localhost:5001/test_streaming"

s = requests.Session()
resp = s.get(url, stream=True)
for chunk in resp.iter_content():
    print(chunk.decode(), end="")
```

It does not work like I expect it to, ie `requests` waits for the whole response to be sent instead of iterating over the stream.

Now if I add line breaks after each chunk of the stream, and therefore change the server-side code to:

```py
@app.route('/test_streaming')
def test_streaming():
    def generate():
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            yield f"{i}\n"  # <- line break added here
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text')
```

then the same client-side request is able to stream result as it is generated by the client.

Why doesn't the code without line breaks work? Is there a way to stream text via Flask without adding line breaks to it?

I have read [Flask's documentation about streaming](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/patterns/streaming/)

But I don't think it applies to my issue as their examples only covers streaming CSV data (which by definition contains line breaks) or streaming a template (which I'm not trying to do here)

I'm using:

- python 3.10.11
- Flask 2.3.2

Comment: Could be the Python line buffer. Try to set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the behavior of the `requests.iter_content()` function. In the [documentation](https:///http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/) it says:

> Iterates over the response data. When stream=True is set on the request, this avoids reading the content at once into memory for large responses. The chunk size is the number of bytes it should read into memory. This is not necessarily the length of each item returned as decoding can take place.

So probably your function *is* reading the data while is being sent, just 1 byte at a time. If you try to iterate more, you'll see that the data actually arrives in different blocks (following server code example):

```
@app.route('/test_streaming')
def test_streaming():
    def generate():
        for i in range(100000):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            yield str(i)
    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text')
```

As for the line breaks, can be the fact that the `iter_content` recognize line breaks as a "block termination" character, but I don't know for sure.